# how to turn off oauth consent screen after allow permission?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have 2 questions in this thread.

1. I use google API authentication. After run the code to make credential, the browser opens OAuth consent screen in new tab (google chrome). How can I show it as a popup dialog, not open new tab anymore?
2. After I click accept button, API return the text that tell me token is received in that tab. How can I turn it off immediatelly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on the language you are using. The consent form is just a web page so assuming you can create your own popup window with a web browser just feed it the consent URI.
2. You cant really the authentication code is returned to you by the authentication server as a web page its going to have to open up someplace.